# Is there an OpenGrok API?

Tags: java, perl, api, search, opengrok

Is there an API for [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)?
I'm interested in mining the results in either Perl or Java.
At the moment, I could perform HTML scrapping against the results, but seems less-than-ideal.

As per its website, it leverages Lucene, but no real info on how to connect to it other than via HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Starting in OpenGrok 0.13, there is a simple REST API.

With OpenGrok 1.0 there is a [JSON API](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/Web-services).

Comment: Apparently it's only available through localhost

Answer (score 2):

Opengrok supports a [command line interface](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-install-OpenGrok#wiki-CLI__Command_Line_Interface_Usage) that may be able to provide what you're looking for.

Example:

```
$ java -cp ./opengrok.jar org.opensolaris.opengrok.search.Search -R /var/opengrok/etc/configuration.xml -f "My Search"
```

Answer (score 1):

This fork has a JSON API: https://github.com/Goyaka/OpenGrok/blob/f70d78e743a0a389b46ea36c4785182ee8f03e13/src/com/goyaka/opengrok/web/SearchServlet.java

This issue discusses it: https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/issues/422